# I don't know AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys' in python selenium. I tried all solutions but still problem

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, input, attributeerror

There is an Attribution problem. I tried all references but I can't fix it.
This code is only successful when the cursor is on the textbox.

code:

```
browser.get('https://zeus.gist.ac.kr/sys/main/main.do')

browser.implicitly_wait(10)
iframe = browser.find_element_by_id("TOBE_JSP")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)
browser.find_element_by_id('mainframe_VFrameSet_HFrameSet_leftFrame_form_gridMenu_body_gridrow_7').click()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.find_element_by_id('mainframe_VFrameSet_HFrameSet_leftFrame_form_gridMenu_body_gridrow_12').click()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
bodytemp = browser.find_element_by_xpath("~~~~/input").click()
bodytemp.send_keys("36.5")
```

element:

```
<div id="~~~~" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 54px; height: 18px; cursor: text; user-select: initial;"><input id="mainframe_VFrameSet_HFrameSet_MDIFrameSet_ctxFrameSet_ctxFrame_PERS07^PERS07_08^005^AmcDailyTempRegE_form_div_sample_divMain_divForm_edtTemp_input" tabindex="-1" style="border: none; outline: none; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 54px; height: 18px; cursor: text; font: 9pt NanumGothic; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); text-align: left; padding: 0px 1px;"></div>
 <input id="~~~~_input" tabindex="-1" style="border: none; outline: none; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; background-color: transparent; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 54px; height: 18px; cursor: text; font: 9pt NanumGothic; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); text-align: left; padding: 0px 1px;">
```

And I also tried:

```
bodytemp = browser.find_element_by_xpath("~~~~/input")
bodytemp.send_keys("36.5")
```

->selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)

It sometimes runs well(maybe 1/10..?)

And I also tried:

```
bodytemp = browser.find_element_by_xpath("~~~~/input")
bodytemp.clear()
bodytemp.send_keys("36.5")
```

-> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clear'

The element is visible. I already check it.
please help me. I can't sleep.

Comment: That most likely means that the element wasn't found. Try printing bodytemp. If it says 'None' that means the you're not finding the element.

Comment: But sometimes it works well. Then does it find the element well then?

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it to click and send_keys both.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("~~~~_input").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("~~~~_input").send_keys("36.5")
```